# Implementation of native components of mono touch or mono droid with Xamarin.Forms components

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to use native controls of mono touch or mono droid libraries e.g. UIView (iOS), TextView (Android) etc. with Xamarins.Forms components (StackLayout, AbsoluteLayout, Frame etc.)? The issue which i am facing is, I want to add a UILabel (iOS) in my Xamarin.Forms' StackLayout. But I didn't get any way to implement this. Can anyone tell me you can I achieve this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't want to use the Forms Label component then you would have to create a custom renderer that uses UILabel on the iOS renderer, TextView on Android and TextBlock on Windows Phone.

Comment: If i feel desire to add map of ios with xamain.forms layout then what should i do?